# Maven POM to build based on single source file following the resources used by it

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a Java application, many classes of which can also function as stand-alone utilities. But these classes (or utilities) depends on some other classes and few libraries. Since it is a decent size project, the directory structure is moderately large with so many nested directories.

I am new to maven. Is it possible for maven, given a single Java source file, identify which other Java classes are needed to compile it and find them on its own (if just 1 main Java class is specified)?

I want to be able to build a JAR using maven for a particular utility (.Java file) including all other classes that it depends on.

I have tried using `<includes></includes>` in `maven-compiler-plugin` to specify the package which contains my desired Utility class but the problem it poses is that then maven will try to compile all other classes in that package, which in turn will need hundreds of other classes and so on.

I also tried to play around with `build-helper-maven-plugin` but couldn't make it to work either.
I am looking for any neater and cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: If each 'utility' is in a separate folder then you could model the entire project as a multi-module maven project with any individual utility being one module, and any common jars being in separate modules.

Comment: unfortunately, that is not the case. It's all a single project and those 'utilities' are not in separate folders.